# Keras - How do I turn a 5d Tensor into a 3d one by getting rid of the last three dimensions?

Tags: numpy, keras, keras-layer

In Keras, I have a (100, 200, 300, 400, 500) Tensor outputted from a Layer, and want to turn it into a (100, 200, 300*400*500) one before feeding it into a new Layer. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a [keras.layers.Reshape](https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape) layer:

```
from keras.layers import Reshape

# ...
model.add(Reshape((100,200,300*400*500)))
# ...
```

or

```
model.add(Reshape((-1,200,300*400*500)))
```

Comment: What if I have a shape of (?, 200, 300, 400, 500) instead?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first dimension is the batch size, you ignore it:

```
model.add(Reshape(200,300*400*500))
```